# The proof of Zariski-Nagata Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, proof-explanation, modules, homological-algebra

I'm studying symbolic powers from "Singularities and Foliations. Geometry, Topology and Applications".
I have some questions about the proof of Theorem 2.12:

"Let $K$ be a field and $R$ be a finitely generated regular $K$-algebra. Then \begin{equation}\mathfrak{p}^{(n)}=\bigcap_{\mathfrak{m}\in Max(R), \mathfrak{p}\subset \mathfrak{m}}\mathfrak{m}^n\end{equation}"

In order to prove $\mathfrak{p}^{(n)}\supseteq\bigcap\mathfrak{m}^n$, it suffices to show that
\begin{equation}
\bigcap_{\mathfrak{m}\in Max(R), \mathfrak{p}\subseteq \mathfrak{m}}(\mathfrak{m}^n.R/\mathfrak{p}^{(n)})=0.
\end{equation}
It has defined $M=R/\mathfrak{p}^{(n)}$ and $M_i=\mathfrak{p}^i.R/\mathfrak{p}^{(n)}$ and it's mentioned in the proof that $M_i$ is an $R/\mathfrak{p}$-module. I couldn't find a well-defined multiplication between elements of $M_i$ and $R/\mathfrak{p}$. So why is this statement true? I would be thankful for any help